# Access - Only take row from table of max year

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access that holds students previous qualifications. It has multiple lines per students dependent on the number of previous qualifications they have. The data has the year of the qualification in it.

I want to create a sub-query that only has the most recent qualification in it (i.e. the latest year). I have tried `max` and `last` in the query for the year, but because I am bringing out other fields, it is still pulling out all the qualifications rather than just the latest one.

```
StudentID     Qualificationlevel    QualificationType   MaxOfYearAwarded

10203         Postgraduate/Masters          MSc                2016
10203         Undergraduate                 BSc                2013
```

So in the example above, I want to ONLY have the top row being pulled as it is 2016 and therefore later than 2013.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a simple task
Just use a subquery as a condition.

To group the query, use a `WHERE` condition in the subquery. Note that, since we're querying the same table twice, we will need to use table aliases

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.YearAwarded = (
   SELECT Max(s.YearAwarded) 
   FROM MyTable s 
   WHERE s.StudentID = t.StudentID
)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. How would I group by StudentID? So I just have every student and their max qualification? At the moment the SQL you provided just pulls off those qualifications done in 2017 :)

Comment: Erik, thank you so much. I use Access quite a lot, but never really touch the SQL part..... I should really get to grips with it as your answer works PERFECTLY!